# "wget" failing to retrieve input file because of name on my computer

Tags: download, wget, bookmarks

I've been doing my very best to try a solution that works. I hope I can get my answer here.

I'm trying to download a lot of images from my bookmarks folder, and I'm trying to extract them separately. I found a solution that involved "wget", a program I've never heard of before, but I figured I may as well try it out. Here's the command I'm trying to run:

```
wget --recursive --level 1 --page-requisites --convert-links --force-html -P C:\Users\(user)\Desktop\images\ --input-file C:\Users\(user)\Downloads\bookmarks_9_17_20.html
```

As you can see, I'm trying to download all of the images in bulk from my exported bookmark file. Unfortunately, I run across **this error:**

```
--2020-09-17 00:44:54--  http://(user last name)%5Cdesktop%5Cimages%5C/
Resolving (user last name)\\desktop\\images\\ ((user last name)\\desktop\\images\\)... failed: No such host is known. .
wget: unable to resolve host address '(user last name)\\desktop\\images\\'
--2020-09-17 00:44:54--  http://(user last name)%5Cdownloads%5Cbookmarks_9_17_20.html/
Resolving (user last name)\\downloads\\bookmarks_9_17_20.html ((user last name)\\downloads\\bookmarks_9_17_20.html)... failed: No such host is known. .
wget: unable to resolve host address '(user last name)\\downloads\\bookmarks_9_17_20.html'
C:/Users/(user first name): No such file or directory
No URLs found in C:/Users/(user first name).
```

Sorry for the major censorship -- I like to keep my privacy. So it seems as if wget is breaking off the directory when it reaches my name because my name has a space in it. Does the program expect an underscore? If not, *does it even use a character to symbolize a space?*

I am lost regarding solutions. No matter what I search, no matter how detailed I describe the situation, I can't find a solution. Hopefully, you guys have a solution to how I can prevent wget from splitting the directory.

**All help is appreciated!**

Answer (score 0):

It is a late answer, but most likely you could either enclose path in quotes or escape space by putting \ before space. The backslashes in windows should be double backslashes as first one will be escape character and 2nd one then to tells to escape the backslash.

The path could even work with forward slashes as folder separators, that might depend more on application code and how it gets the windows path.

Solution should be theoretically either:

```
wget --recursive --level 1 --page-requisites --convert-links --force-html -P C:\\Users\\(First name)\ (Last name)\\Desktop\\images\\ --input-file C:\\Users\\(First name)\ (Last name)\\Downloads\\bookmarks_9_17_20.html
```

or

```
wget --recursive --level 1 --page-requisites --convert-links --force-html -P "C:\Users\(user)\Desktop\images\" --input-file "C:\Users\(user)\Downloads\bookmarks_9_17_20.html"
```